PHP 8.2 FPM + OPcache + multiuser environment + blank page issue (Child exited with code 70)
We are facing a weird issue for months, getting a white page for all websites with multiple errors like below
[02-Jul-2024 11:36:55] WARNING: [pool site1] child 3122781 exited with code 70 after 31.975230 seconds from start

Having below configuration.
**OS :** Ubuntu 22.04
**Apache :** 2.4.54
**PHP :** 8.2 - FPM
**Server configuration:** 4 core CPU, 16GB RAM.

We have multiple websites with each have their own pool with below config.
/etc/php/8.2/fpm/pool.d/site1.conf
group = site1
listen = /run/php/site1.sock
listen.owner = site1
listen.group = site1
listen.mode = 0666

pm = ondemand
pm.max_children = 10
pm.start_servers = 0
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 5
pm.process_idle_timeout = 10;
pm.max_requests = 50

security.limit_extensions = .php
php_admin_flag[allow_url_fopen] = on
php_admin_flag[log_errors] = on
php_admin_value[short_open_tag] = on
php_value[error_log] = /home/site1/logs/fpm.error.log
php_value[upload_max_filesize]=50M
php_value[post_max_size]=60M
php_value[max_input_vars]=20000
php_value[max_execution_time]=4500
php_value[session.cookie_lifetime]=0
php_value[memory_limit]=1024M
php_value[session.gc_maxlifetime]=3600
php_value[error_reporting]=85

request_slowlog_timeout = 60
slowlog = /home/$pool/logs/fpm.error.log.slow

With php modules enabled as below
[PHP Modules]
bcmath
bz2
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
gmp
hash
iconv
igbinary
imagick
imap
intl
ionCube Loader
json
ldap
libxml
mbstring
mcrypt
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDFlib
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
random
readline
redis
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
soap
sockets
sodium
SPL
ssh2
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tidy
tokenizer
vips
xml
xmlreader
xmlrpc
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zip
zlib

[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
the ionCube PHP Loader

We are facing the blank white page randomly with php8.2-fpm, sites are down, when I check service php8.2-fpm status, it was active.
Memory consumption at that time was also not much, almost 80 % of RAM was available.

I tried to reproduce similar/same case in my local environment, able to do it with below steps.
Different pool for different user (multi-user PHP-FPM configured)
OPcache configured with
opcache.force_restart_timeout=10
site1_document_root/longrunningscript.php
<?php sleep(1000);

site2_document_root/clearcache.php
<?php opcache_reset();


Run longrunningscript.php

_opcache debug log_
Tue Jul  2 16:04:46 2024 (3137485): Message Cached script '/home/site1/wait.php'


Run clearcache.php

_opcache debug log_
Tue Jul  2 16:04:51 2024 (3137480): Message Cached script '/home/site2/kill.php'
Tue Jul  2 16:04:51 2024 (3137480): Debug Restart Scheduled! Reason: user


After 10 seconds run any script of site2

_opcache debug log_
Tue Jul  2 16:05:20 2024 (3137535): Warning Forced restart at 1719936320 (after 10 seconds), locked by 3137485
Tue Jul  2 16:05:20 2024 (3137535): Warning Attempting to kill locker 3137485
Tue Jul  2 16:05:20 2024 (3137535): Warning Failed to send SIGKILL to locker 3137485: Operation not permitted
Tue Jul  2 16:05:20 2024 (3137535): Error Cannot kill process 3137485!

It seems OPcache clear and restart cache is not able to do necessary things, it is going to kill_all_lockers. But processes running with other users are not being killed, and happens this crash.

Quite a lot of issues here.
It looks like your opcache is running out of memory - if you simply made it bigger then issues around the restart become irrelevant.
You have scripts which take longer than opcache.force_restart_timeout to complete - if you made them faster, not only would you be able to execute a restart, it would improve the user experience. Again this make the restart issue irrelevant rather than solving it directly.
As for the issue itself:
Failed to send SIGKILL to locker 3137485: Operation not permitted

I believe opcache uses a single shared memory region, even if PHP is running as different UIDs. Normally one user cannot kill the processes of other users. You could change this by setting CAP_KILL on the executable, but this would open the door to DOS issues and somewhat undermine the objectives of using separate uids.
(IMHO this is a scenario PHP & FPM should handle - you might consider checking if there is a bug/feature request and logging one if not).
That just leaves the option of forcing PHP to use separate opcaches for each user. That means running each pool in a separate host or container.
